# I can't get VBoxVmService started due to Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure

Tags: windows, service, virtualbox

I have built a Windows 11 mini box this week with the purpose of it working as a home server, and between others I have Homeassistant running in a Virtualbox VM.

Ideally, I want everything running without having to log on, so I started exploring achieving this via VBoxVmService and the instructions here https://www.roamit.com.au/post/virtualbox-auto-startup-and-shutdown.

However, following the steps closely, when I start the service I get the following message:

```
Windows could not start the VBoxVmService service on Local Computer.
Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

My user with which I set up Win11 is my main one, tied to my online MS account (I have reasons) and I have triple-checked that the username that I'm using is the correct one, which resolves to my local user name (the same one as under C:\Users).

Can anyone please point to what am I doing wrong, or what could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out I found my own answer that I hadn't come across previously: [stackoverflow.com/a/54928758/22265949](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928758/22265949) Locking my screen and logging in with my password instead of PIN seems to be the required magic to make it work.